# Get computers in a workgroup

Tags: c#

How can I query all accessible computers that are in a particular workgroup?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx

Comment: Hopefully you're wanting a list of machines that are currently in the workgroup (i.e. switched on and on the network) - otherwise there's no answer.

Comment: @Damien: yes I meant that, is `available computer` not the correct term for this? (Serious question)

Comment: personally, I found `available` a bit ambiguous. `accessible` would be a stronger word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the active directory API - check the [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9cddzaa.aspx) class (don't forget to add reference to `System.DirectoryServices.dll`).
Here is a short example:

```
    using (DirectoryEntry workgroup = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup"))
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry child in workgroup.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
        }
    }
```