# Get devices from "Network"

Tags: .net, networking

I have been searching for about 2 hours now without any luck, maybe I am searching for the wrong things... But, Here's what I need:

When you go to "Computer" in the Start Menu of Windows (Vista and 7), and you then click on "Network" on the left hand side, you see a couple of devices.
I need to get the computers from that list of devices in .NET (C# or VB, doesn't matter.).
Specifically, I need thier **ADDRESS**, like \\HOME-PC and so forth.

I have no clue on how to do this. I have looked through the object browser, and on Google, but no luck.

Comment: In searching Stackoverflow I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581140/in-c-how-do-i-get-the-list-of-local-computer-names-like-what-one-gets-viewing-th

Comment: Awesome, next time, you should post it as an answer :D Can't really give you credit this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is query the WorkGroup for other computers, to do so you could use the code [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178364/get-computers-in-a-workgroup)

Comment: Ah, ofcourse! Workgroup! I should've thought about that! Thank you, this resolves my problem! It will still only get something like "HOME-PC" instead of "\\HOME-PC", but I guess if the names are correct, I can just add "\\" infront of it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

see [Retreiving a list of network computer names](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx), i guess it is what you are looking for

Comment: Also a great answer, thank you for trying to help. Check out sternr's answer, it seems a lot simpler, and possably more reliable :)